# Error: el método no está definido para el tipo

Tags: java

Tengo 3 clases, `Triangulo`, `Punto` y el `Main11`, la cuestión es que en la clase `Main` me pidieron hacer un arreglo para dibujar unas figuras:

-------clase Triangulo

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JColorChooser;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Triangulo {

    private Punto puntoA;
    private Punto  puntoB;
    private Punto puntoC;

    public Triangulo(int AX, int AY, int BX, int BY, int CX, int CY) {
        super();
        this.puntoA = new Punto(AX,AY);
        this.puntoB =new Punto(BX,BY);
        this.puntoC= new Punto(CX,CY);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Estado del tirangulo\n "
                +"\nPunto A\n"+
                puntoA+
                "\nPunto B\n"+
                puntoB+
                "\nPunto C\n"+
                puntoC
                ;
    }

    public void mostrarEstado() {
        System.out.println(this.toString());
        System.out.println();
    }

    public double calcularPerimetro() {
        return this.puntoB.calcularDistancia(this.puntoA) + this.puntoB.calcularDistancia(this.puntoC)+this.puntoC.calcularDistancia(this.puntoA);
    }

    public double areaTriangulo() {
        double area=Math.abs((puntoA.getX()*(puntoB.getY()-puntoC.getY())+puntoB.getX()
        *(puntoC.getY()-puntoA.getY())+puntoC.getX()*(puntoA.getY()-puntoB.getY()))/2.0);
        return area;
    }

    boolean tieneMayorAreaQue(Triangulo otroTriangulo) {
        if(this.areaTriangulo()>otroTriangulo.areaTriangulo()) {
        return true;
                }
                return false;
    }


}
```

-------------------clase Punto

```
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Punto {

    private int x;
    private int y;


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "X=" + x +"\n"
               +"Y=" + y + "";
    }


    public Punto(int x, int y) {
        super();
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }


    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }


    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }
    public void mostrar() {
        System.out.println(this.toString());
    }

    public double calcularDistancia(Punto pb) {
        double dis=Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x-pb.getX(),2)
                +Math.pow(y-pb.getY(),2));
        return dis;
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.fillOval(x-1,
                y-1,
                2,2);
    }
}
```

------------------Clase Main11

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JColorChooser;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main11 {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Circulo []cicle=new Circulo[3];
        cicle [0]=new Circulo (50,100,50);      
        cicle [1]=new Circulo (20,30,20);
        cicle [2]=new Circulo (60,30,60);

        Punto []squa=new Punto[3];
        squa [0]=new Punto(100,10);
        squa [1]=new Punto(300,60);
        squa [2]=new Punto(450,90);

        Triangulo []choc =new Triangulo[2];
        choc [0]=new Triangulo(15,12,30,40,60,50);
        choc [1]=new Triangulo(18,20,60,80,30,30);

        Color color=JColorChooser.showDialog(null,"seleccione un color",Color.white);

        JPanel panel;
        panel = new JPanel() {
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                this.setBackground(color);

                for (int a=0;a<3;a++) {
                    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                    cicle[a].paint(g);
                }
                for (int a=0;a<3;a++) {
                    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                    squa[a].paint(g);
                }
                for (int a=0;a<2;a++) {
                    g.setColor(Color.RED);
                    choc[a].paint(g);
                }

            }
        };
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,panel);
```

El problema viene en la línea `choc[a].paint(g);` ya que me dice:

> The method paint(Graphics) is undefined for the type Triangulo

y no sé realmente qué hacer para solucionarlo. ¿Por qué me sale ese error y cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la clase Triangulo no tienes definido el método paint por eso te indica ese error y tendrías que extender de JPanel.

Para pintar el triangulo podrías usar lo siguiente:

```
  public void paint(Graphics g) {
    int posicionesX[] = {10, 20, 30};
    int posicionesY[] = {100, 20, 100};
    int numeroPuntos = 3;

    g.drawPolygon(posicionesX, posicionesY, numeroPuntos);
  }
```

Tendrías que asignar al array posicionesX y posicionesY los puntos que tienes definidos en tu clase triangulo.
Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Para solucionarlo recuerda extender JPanel en `Triangulo.class`

```
public class Triangulo extends JPanel {
....
```